# How do we configure plan for SQL database for Azure using Terraform?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, terraform

I am using Terraform to configure the infrastructure on Azure. I am creating SQL database using Terraform template and I am able to create the database but by default the **Standard** plan is set for the database. Is it possible to configure the plan to **Basic** plan using the template?

This is the template that I am using: -

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "Test-ResourceGroup"
  location = "Central India"
}
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "test" {
    name = "name-test-dev" 
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
    location = "Central India"
    version = "12.0"
    administrator_login = "test-admin"
    administrator_login_password = "test-password"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_database" "test" {
  name                = "test-dev"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
    location = "Central India"
    server_name = "${azurerm_sql_server.test.name}"  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`edition` argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/sql_database.html#edition) on the database to `Basic`

```
resource "azurerm_sql_database" "test" {
  name                = "test-dev"
  edition             = "Basic"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
    location = "Central India"
    server_name = "${azurerm_sql_server.test.name}"  
}
```

Comment: Thank you @laika, your answer helped me to create database with Basic plan. Marking it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

hope helps

Create an Azure SQL Server Database with a SQL script initialization

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/metadevpro/sqlserver-seed/azurerm/1.0.0

```
module "azurerm_sql_sever_init" { 
  source             = "Azure/database-seed/azurerm" 
  location           = "westeurope"
  resource_group     = "myresourcegroup007"
  db_server_fqdn     = "${azurerm_sql_server.db1.fully_qualified_domain_name}"
  sql_admin_username = "${azurerm_sql_server.db1.administrator_login}"
  sql_admin_password = "${azurerm_sql_server.db1.administrator_login_password}"
  db_name             = "mydatabase"
  init_script_file    = "mydatabase.init.sql"
  log_file            = "mydatabase.init.log"

  tags = {
    environment = "qa"
    project     = "acme"
    provisioner = "terraform"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but laika's answer solve the query I was looking into.